# Juggling Scala, Antlr and Java in a Gradle build

Tags: java, scala, gradle, antlr

I have a project that is setup as follows:
1. Antlr files under src/main/antlr
2. Scala files under src/main/scala
3. Java files under src/main/java

Java code depends on Scala generated classes which in turn depend on source generated by Antlr.

This layout is replicated for tests. I have no additional sourceSets defined except for the tweak i am trying out as shown i n the linked file.

We use Antlr 3 so cannot use the plugin shipped with Gradle. We do use the Scala plugin though. According to numerous suggestions i have reversed the dependency between Scala and Java compilation and have modified the Scala srcDirs to include $buildDir/generated/src under which Antlr task dumps its output and also the Java sources thus getting scalac to joint compile.

The problem that i now face is that the 'test' task does not see any of the generated files even though I see generated classes under the build directory. The strange part seems to be that test compilation succeeds but the scala/Antlr classes do not seem to be on the classpath.

Here is my gradle build script.

```
sourceCompatibility = '1.6'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'scala'

configurations {
    antlr3
    scalaBuild
}

sourceSets {
    test {
        java{
            runtimeClasspath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath + files("${buildDir}/jars")
        }
    }
}

def antlrSource = "src/main/antlr"
def antlrOutput = "$buildDir/generated/src"

dependencies {
    antlr3 (
        [group: 'org.antlr', name: 'antlr', version: '3.3']
    )
    compile (
        [group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: '2.9.2'],
        [group: 'com.googlecode.kiama', name: 'kiama_2.9.2', version: '1.2.0'],
        [group: 'net.sf.jgrapht', name: 'jgrapht', version: '0.8.3'],           
        [group: 'org.antlr', name: 'antlr-runtime', version: '3.3'],
        [group: 'org.antlr', name: 'stringtemplate', version: '3.2.1'],
        [group: 'com.beust', name: 'jcommander', version: '1.7']
    )
    testCompile (
        [group: 'org.scalatest', name: 'scalatest_2.9.2', version: '1.8'],
        [group: 'org.antlr', name: 'gunit', version: '3.3']
    )
}

test.doFirst {
    configurations.testRuntime.each{ println it }
}

task generateGrammarSource {
    description = "Generates Java sources from Antlr3 grammars."
    inputs.dir file(antlrSource)
    outputs.dir file(antlrOutput)
} << {
  mkdir(antlrOutput)
  sourceSets.main.scala.srcDirs = sourceSets.main.scala.srcDirs + ["src/main/java", antlrOutput]
  sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = []

  def grammars = fileTree(antlrSource).include("**/*.g")

  ant.java(classname: 'org.antlr.Tool', fork: true, classpath: "${configurations.antlr3.asPath}") {
     arg(line: "-o ${antlrOutput}")
     arg(line: grammars.files.join(" "))
  }
}

task extraJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: compileScala) {
    archiveName = "duplicate-classes.jar"
    destinationDir = file("${buildDir}/jars")
    from "${buildDir}/classes"
}

artifacts {
    scalaBuild extraJar
}

compileScala.taskDependencies.values = compileScala.taskDependencies.values - 'compileJava'
compileJava.dependsOn(compileScala)
compileScala.dependsOn generateGrammarSource
```

Can someone please guide me in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The build script has several smells:

1. It's unclear why `files("${buildDir}/jars")` is added to test runtime class path.
2. It's `sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath`, not `sourceSets.test.java.runtimeClasspath`.
3. Task `generateGrammarSource` should have type `JavaExec`, rather than a task action that calls `ant.java`.
4. Scala source dirs need to be configured in the *configuration phase* rather than the *execution phase*.
5. It's unclear why the `compileScala`->`compileJava` dependency is inverted. In the build at hand this is definitely not necessary, since `compileJava` doesn't have anything to do after its source dirs were "removed" in favor of joint compilation.

That said, without a reproducible example it's hard to say what exactly causes the problem at hand. The first improvement I'd make is to declare the Scala source dirs at the top level, outside a task action. This solves 4. above.

Comment: Alright, I've made the change to move those two lines to the configuration step. I need to create a simple example for you to look at which will, hopefully, highlight the problem. Will post both the example and the updated Gradle script soon.

Comment: I am going to try and close this question. Although I would have loved a closure, we've been unfortunately asked to revert to Maven.